# Android: Как изменить задний фон у элемента menu в тулбаре

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragment, menu

Нужно изменить бекграунд у `showAsAction = always` элемента как на примере.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я пробовал делать кастомный xml через `layer-list` с бекграундом и картинкой, но в результате бекграунд был только внутри иконки, а не по всему периметру элемента в меню.
Так же пробовал `android(app):background`, `android(app):itemBackground`

Разметка меню:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
    android:title="Search"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_filter"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_slider"
    app:iconTint="@color/green"
    android:iconTint="@color/green"
    android:title="filters"
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
    />
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Привязка меню к лейауту:

```
val menuHost: MenuHost = binding.searchAnimeToolbar
    menuHost.addMenuProvider(object : MenuProvider {
        override fun onCreateMenu(menu: Menu, menuInflater: MenuInflater) {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu)
            val menuFilterButton = menu.findItem(R.id.action_filter)


        }

        override fun onMenuItemSelected(menuItem: MenuItem): Boolean {
            if(menuItem.itemId == R.id.action_filter) {
                Toast.makeText(context, "coming soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

            return true
        }
    }, viewLifecycleOwner)
```